# Counting odd and even compositions of integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> > A composition of the number $n$ with $k$ summands is the representation
> >     $$ n = a_1 + \cdots + a_k$$ with integers $a_i \geq 1, 1 \leq i \leq k$. The order of the summands is important.
>
> Prove: There are as many compositions of *n* with *k* even summands as compositions of *n-k* with *k* odd summands exist.

Hi!

I don't have any idea how to prove that as I don't know how to handle this "odd" and "even" stuff. Bijection? Induction?

Could you please help me to understand this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A bijection will do (subtract one from each $a_i$).

Comment: @jspecter of course, I never thought it could be so simple, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If $x$ is even then $x-1$ is odd, and vice versa.

Comment: Filmus thanks! No idea why I missed that...